# Using custom created components in tapestry

Tags: java, tapestry

I recently started learning about the Tapestry framework. I was following a book example about creating a custom component and using it in code. For some reason the text from the component is not showing (I only see the hello world text). Here is the .java and tml files:

```
public class Index
{
  public Index() {

  }

    public String getHello()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Index tml :

```
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/
tapestry_5_3.xsd">
<head>
<title>Tapestry 5 Book</title>
</head>
<body>
<t:MyComponent/>

<h1> ${hello} </h1> 


</body>
</html>
```

MyComponent.java

```
public class MyComponent {

    public String getStuff()
    {
        return "Random stuff";
    }
}
```

MyComponent.tml

```
<span> ${stuff} </span>
```

I would also like to say that the .java files are in their corresponding packages (pages and components in main/java...) and .tml files are in their corresponding packages in resources. My question is, why is the component text not showing ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks OK to me, so it's really just a case of absolutely verifying that the MyComponent.tml is in the right place, and visible on the classpath at runtime.  This could be an issue with IDE configuration, for example.

For component class org.example.MyComponent, the typical place is src/main/resources/org/example/MyComponent.tml, but you have to make sure your IDE is exporting files inside src/main/resources.

Comment: Well this the folder where I can find the MyComponent.tml file 
src\main\resources\com\example\tutorial\components

Comment: I also put a System.out.println line in the MyComponent constructor to test if the constructor gets called. The constructor wasn't called.

Comment: Next ste is to post the console output at startup; it lists all the pages and components that Tapestry identifies at startup.

Comment: I solved the problem by putting this code : <html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">  in a single line :).